# capture expect ssh output to variable

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, capture

Hey am new to bash scripts and was wondering how would I capture the output of the `ssh` command into a bash variable? I looked around and cant seem to get it right. I have tried  puts `$expect_out(buffer)` but when `echo` it says variable does not exist

I know the response should be just one line and if I want to save that into a variable `response` and then `echo` it how would I do that?

Comment: Include the code you have now and the exact output you are getting currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic idea can be something like as below.

1. `spawn` the ssh session
2. make proper login
3. Send each commands with `send`
4. Wait for desired output with `expect`

Example:

```
spawn ssh $user@$domain
expect "password" { send "$pwd\r"}
expect "#"; # This '#' is nothing but the terminal prompt
send "$cmd\r"
expect "#"
puts $expect_out(buffer);  #Will print the output of the 'cmd' output now.
```

The word to wait for after executing the command can vary based on your system. It can be `#` or `$` or `>` or `:`; So, make sure you are giving the correct one. Or, you can provide a generalized pattern for the prompt as such

```
set prompt "#|>|:|\\\$"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'
```

While using the `expect` after sending the commands, it can be used as

```
expect -re $prompt; #Using regex to match the pattern`
```